# Netmask ordering prioritization not working?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I've a **server** with 2 IP's.

- 10.10.1.50 (255.255.255.0)
- 10.10.2.50 (255.255.255.0)

I've also a **DC** which has it's IP on 10.10.1.30 and has no way to reach 10.10.2.50.

When I ping the **server**  from **DC** it responds with 10.10.2.50. So I went with the obvious way to deal with it and disabled Round Robin, kept Netmask ordering enabled

```
    dwLogLevel               = 00000000
    dwDebugLevel             = 00000000
    dwRpcProtocol            = 00000005
    dwNameCheckFlag          = 00000002
    cAddressAnswerLimit      = 0
    dwRecursionRetry         = 3
    dwRecursionTimeout       = 8
    dwDsPollingInterval      = 180
 Configuration Flags:
    fBootMethod                  = 3
    fAdminConfigured             = 1
    fAllowUpdate                 = 1
    fDsAvailable                 = 1
    fAutoReverseZones            = 1
    fAutoCacheUpdate             = 0
    fSlave                       = 0
    fNoRecursion                 = 0
    fRoundRobin                  = 0
    fStrictFileParsing           = 0
    fLooseWildcarding            = 0
    fBindSecondaries             = 0
    fWriteAuthorityNs            = 0
    fLocalNetPriority            = 1
  Aging Configuration:
    ScavengingInterval           = 0
    DefaultAgingState            = 0
    DefaultRefreshInterval       = 168
    DefaultNoRefreshInterval     = 168
```

But even  after Round Robin is disabled and Netmask ordering seems to be correct the wrong result is returned.

**LocalNetPriorityNetMask** is set to `0x000000ff (255)` so it seems to be set correctly for **class C**. So why it doesn't work as it should? What am I missing? Both records of the **server** have same date/time in DNS. I know I could fix it by disabling netmask ordering and changing the times a bit but this will break it for servers that relay on accessing the server via 10.10.2.50 IP address.

Server was rebooted multiple times. Usually after reboot the servers do respond properly with 10.10.1.50. After a while 10.10.2.50 comes into play so **DC** can't connect to the server.

Comment: Silly question, but are you doing an `ipconfig/flushdns` between tests to ensure you aren't just hitting the local cache?

Comment: Yes, i was using ipconfig /flushdns. No help.

Comment: not really answering your question here, but multi-homing a DC is generally not a good idea. Why not use a router/L3 switch/... with iphelper if you want multiple subnets? this way you can leave your DC to 1 ip address. Saves a LOT of trouble

Comment: Goez DC has only 1 IP. The SERVER has 2. DC is just trying to reach the server in this case SCOM.I asked client to make proper routing but it's not my network. SO i have to fix it without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2010/05/29/dns-and-subnet-priortization-amp-dns-round-robin.aspx), they have changed the logic more than one time between OS releases.

You did not mention if you tried this already, which should enable Subnet Priorization on Vista/2008+:

```
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters  
DWORD = OverrideDefaultAddressSelection  
Value data: = 0
```

I can see that your flags say that subnet priorization is enabled, so this might be a longshot.

Comment: I've added this on servers and after reboot seems to be working. Before accepting I'm gonna give it some time to not stop working ;-) Thank you.